# Citation brackets at the wrong place with natbib

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I use `natbib` with the following customization:

```
\RequirePackage{natbib}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\setcitestyle{square,aysep={},yysep={;}}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,  % false: boxed links; true: colored links
  linkcolor=blue,   % color of internal links (change box color with linkbordercolor)
  citecolor=blue,   % color of links to bibliography
  filecolor=blue,   % color of file links
  urlcolor=blue
}
```

When I use `\cite` I get:

[image]

but what I want is:

[image]

How can I do this?

Comment: Use \citep, see the documentation of natbib.

Comment: That works, thanks! Please write it in an answer so that I can accept it. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\citep` instead of `\cite`. See the documentation of natbib for details.